# Complex or-query using QueryOver API

Tags: nhibernate

I have a (simplified) class hierarchy such as this:

```
public class Order
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to query Orders that match on either CompanyName, City or Zip of the Address - but on either the Order or the associated Customer.

I have gotten as far as:

```
public IList<Order> FindOrders(string search, ISession session)
{
    var orders = session.QueryOver<Order>()
          .Where(o => o.Address.City == search || o.Address.Zip == search || o.CompanyName == search).List();
}
```

How do I include the customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the customer address?  If so, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
public IList<Order> FindOrders(string search, ISession session)
{
    var orders = session.QueryOver<Order>(() => orderAlias)
          .JoinAlias(() => orderAlias.Customer, () => customerAlias)
          .Where(() => orderAlias.Address.City == search || orderAlias.Address.Zip == search || orderAlias.CompanyName == search)
          .Or(() => customerAlias.Address.City == search || customerAlias.Address.Zip == search || customerAlias.CompanyName == search)
          .List();
}
```

If you find you're writing a lot of queries like this, you may want to consider doing some kind of fulltext search to make your life easier (I'd recommend lucene.net, possibly via NHibernate.Search)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for :-). Thanks! I'll have a look at lucene too.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked.  Lucene won't necessarily make your life easier, but it will probably make this type of search easier :)  Full text indexing may be an option also, depending on your database.